# (about using Knockout plugin) how to bind child object array as observablearray to the parent observablearray

Tags: json, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

i'm quite new to knockout plugin and i'm trying to build a commentthread with this plugin.  I've some issues when a child comment is bind to parent comment , the expected json stringified object should be some thing like below;

```
[
    {
    CreatedBy: "user 1",
    CreatedOn: Date(),
    Description: "comment 1",
    ChildFeeds: [
                {
                    CreatedBy: "user 2",
                    CreatedOn: Date(),
                    Description: "comment 1-1"
                },
                {
                    CreatedBy: "user 3",
                    CreatedOn: Date(),
                    Description: "comment 1-2"
                },
                {
                    CreatedBy: "user 4",
                    CreatedOn: Date(),
                    Description: "comment 1-3"
                }
                ]
    },
    {
    CreatedBy: "user 5",
    CreatedOn: Date(),
    Description: "comment 2",
    ChildFeeds: [
                {
                    CreatedBy: "user 6",
                    CreatedOn: Date(),
                    Description: "comment 2-1"
                },
                {
                    CreatedBy: "user 7",
                    CreatedOn: Date(),
                    Description: "comment 2-2"
                }
                ]
    },
]
```

but when i run the codes a get the below data instead of the structure of the above one.

```
[
  {
    "CreatedBy": "user 1",
    "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
    "Description": "comment 1",
    "ChildFeeds": [
      {
        "ChildFeeds": [
          {
            "CreatedBy": "user 2",
            "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
            "Description": "comment 1-1"
          },
          {
            "CreatedBy": "user 3",
            "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
            "Description": "comment 1-2"
          },
          {
            "CreatedBy": "user 4",
            "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
            "Description": "comment 1-3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CreatedBy": "user 5",
    "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
    "Description": "comment 2",
    "ChildFeeds": [
      {
        "ChildFeeds": [
          {
            "CreatedBy": "user 6",
            "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
            "Description": "comment 2-1"
          },
          {
            "CreatedBy": "user 7",
            "CreatedOn": "Mon Jan 02 2012 15:50:51 GMT+0200 (Turkey Standard Time)",
            "Description": "comment 2-2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here you'll notice that because of wrong coding , unfortunately i  duplicate the ChildFeeds object array twice for each parent object.. you can find the code from here http://jsfiddle.net/6qAmu/5/

what is the best approach to achieve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your `ChildFeedModel` is an object that contains a `ChildFeeds` observableArray, so when you assign this to a `ChildFeeds` property on your `wallfeedsmodel`, you end up with the double `ChildFeeds`.

One option is to have your `ChildFeedsModel` actually be an observableArray.  So, you would create an observableArray, extend it with any additional methods/properties, then return it.

Something like:

```
var childFeedModel = function(ChildFeeds) {
    var result = ko.observableArray();

    result.addChildFeed = function(tempChildFeed) {

        result.push({
            CreatedBy: tempChildFeed.CreatedBy,
            CreatedOn: tempChildFeed.CreatedOn,
            Description: tempChildFeed.Description
        });
    };

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(ChildFeeds, function(feed) {
       result.addChildFeed(feed); 
    });

    return result;
};
```

I changed it to start with a lower-case letter, because it would now not require a `new` statement when creating one (it always returns a new observableArray).

Now, in your `wallfeedsmodel` you would just assign it like:

```
    return {
        CreatedBy: singlefeed.CreatedBy,
        CreatedOn: singlefeed.CreatedOn,
        Description: singlefeed.Description,
        ChildFeeds: childFeedModel(singlefeed.ChildFeeds)
    };
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xAKK5/